Excitation of a brushless portable generator by a capacitor
I have a brushless portable generator whose excitation current is controlled by a capacitor.
I would love to receive a detailed explanation of how to get without any electronic card - manages to maintain a stable voltage in the generator.
(Can't find a detailed explanation online).
Thanks

It might help if you tell us what make/model generator you have as our crystal ball is rather cloudy at the moment.
